# Output one node previous to where condition matches in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an xml In the format

```
<Session>
 <Record>
  <Y_threshold>85</Y_threshold>

   <XYData>
    <X>200</X>
    <Y>83.5</Y>
   </XYData>
 
   <XYData>
     <X>224</X>
     <Y>84.1</Y>
   </XYData>
            
   <XYData>
     <X>250</X>
     <Y>86.2</Y>
   </XYData>
            
   <XYData>
     <X>282</X>
     <Y>88.3</Y>
   </XYData>
            
   <XYData>
     <X>315</X>
     <Y>90.2</Y>
   </XYData>

 </Record>

 <Record>
  <Y_threshold>90</Y_threshold>

  <XYData>
     <X>200</X>
     <Y>88</Y>
  </XYData>
 
  <XYData>
     <X>224</X>
     <Y>88.5</Y>
  </XYData>
            
  <XYData>
     <X>250</X>
     <Y>89.1</Y>
  </XYData>
            
  <XYData>
     <X>282</X>
     <Y>91.7</Y>
  </XYData>
            
  <XYData>
     <X>315</X>
     <Y>94.5</Y>
   </XYData>

   </Record>
</Session>
```

For each Record I need to get the value of X for the node previous to the FIRST node where Y is greater than Y_threshold is met.

### Clarification in case I've worded that weirdly

In the above example the FIRST node where Y>Y_threshold is met is

```
Record 1
<X>250</X>
<Y>86.2</Y>
(since 86.2 > 85)

Record 2
<X>282</X>
<Y>91.7</Y>
(since 91.7>90)
```

And so the desired output is the **previous** X, i.e. one node **before** the condition was met

```
Record 1
 <X>224</X>

Record 2
<X>250</X>
```

**The Question:** How can i do this using and XSLT 2.0 or 1.0?

Comment: Find the first node that meets the condition, then its immediate preceding sibling.

Comment: yes but how? I'm new to xslt, could you spell it out? Sorry bout that

Comment: sorry bout that I wasn't able to implement it yet, but thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather trivial exercise in XPath. From the context of `Record`, select:

```
XYData[Y > ../Y_threshold][1]/preceding-sibling::XYData[1]/X
```